# How to record x11 Display on remote server

Tags: command-line, xorg, display, remote-x-session

I'm trying to use `cnee` to record the display of a touch device we have our application on (Deployed on ubuntu server 16.04). I don't have any experience with `cnee` and am willing to use a different program if it is more simple to use, so please suggest any suggestions.

I've gotten `cnee` to record keyboard input to test it but that's it.

The command I am trying on my device is

```
cnee --record --display 0 -o displaytest.xns
```

I don't know if it makes any difference but my application is on a remote device. I'm using `ssh` to input the command,no log or keystrokes are needed.

I understand my command may not be doing exactly what I want but I'm trying to go off the `man` page, and this is the closest I've gotten to making it run after working through the error messages I was getting.

Comment: What command are you running to play the `.xns` file on the remote machine? `cnee` is installed on the remote machine, you have transmitted the `.xns` file before running `cnee` and you gave it the correct path, didn't you?

Comment: im not running it right now because its not recording. I dont know if that command is actually working because it seems to crash

Comment: What makes you think that? Do you encounter error messages? Please always add additional information directly to your question by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/973997/edit) rather than writing comments.

Comment: right under my cnee command in my question I explain. I can take a photo if you would like and try and post it.

Comment: after about 7 mins of letting it run it gave me an error I will update the question right now

Comment: Does `cnee` produce the output file `displaytest.xns`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68341/discussion-between-dessert-and-jermayne-williams).